# floating UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to have a "floating" UITableViewCell that is always on the screen, either at the top of the list or the bottom depending on what cells are being shown?

In other words, let's say the UITableView section has 100 cells numbered from 0 to 99. And let's say that for some reason the one we want to highlight is number 31. (Maybe it's a ranked list of participants in a contest, and number 31 belongs to the user.) Furthermore let's say that we can fit 10 of these cells on the screen at once.

- if the visible range is above our highlighted cell (eg 2 to 11), then we want the highlighted cell (#31) to be overlaid at the bottom
- if the visible range includes our highlighted cell (eg 27 to 36), then we want the highlighted cell (#31) to be positioned in its natural place
- if the visible range is below our highlighted cell (eg 45 to 54), then we want the highlighted cell (#31) to be overlaid at the top

Any existing classes that do this? The table headers have similar behaviour, but not quite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

you should try using section header and not table header, and have all of the cell under #31 in section 1 and all the cell above #31 in section 2 and the #31 cell as the header of section 2

Comment: but that won't show cell #31 when i'm looking at the range before it (say 2-11). right?

Comment: Right, on 2-11 it will show the section footer, and on, let's say 40-49 it will show section header

Comment: this is a decent workaround, but not exactly what I was hoping was available.